# Describing the matrix product $BB^T$ of the incidence matrix of a directed graph $G=\left< V,E \right>$

Tags: graphs

I would like to discuss a solution with you below please.

Describing the matrix product $BB^T$ of the incidence matrix of a directed graph $G=\left< V,E \right>$.

**Question**: The **incidence matrix** of a directed graph $G=\langle V,E \rangle$ with no self-loops is a $|V| \times |E|$ matrix $B=(b_{ij})$ such that,

$$
b_{ij}=\begin{cases}
    1&      \text{if edge $j$ enters vertex $i$,} \\
-1 & \text{if ege $j$ leaves vertex $i$,} \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

Describe what the entries of the matrix product $BB^T$ represent, where $B^T$ is the transpose of $B$.

**Solution**:
If the elements of $B$  are $b_{ij}$, then the elements of transpose $B^T$ is $b_{ji}$. Now, $$BB^T = \sum_{k \in E}{}(b_{ik}b_{jk}) \tag{1}\label{1}.$$

We then have two cases for $i,j$:

**Case 1**: if $i=j$, means the row in $B$ is multiplied by the column in $B^T$, so we got $-1 \times -1$ together, which produce positive integer. $-1$ means outgoing edge, and same thing when we have $1 \times 1$ means ingoing edges. So total of product gives $\mathit{incoming}(i) + \mathit{outgoing}(i)$ edges of vertex $i$.

**Case 2**: if $i \ne j$, etc.

**Problem**:

- Why in \ref{1} we have $BB^T = \sum_{k \in E}{}(b_{ik}b_{jk})$? I mean what $b_{ik}$ here means? I understand that $k \in E$ means $k$ in the set of edges of graph $G=\langle V, E \rangle$. If we multiply the vectors from a matrix to its transpose, we will get $b_{ij} \times b_{ji}$, so I am not sure why it's written in this form $(b_{ik}b_{jk})$ please?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $k\in V$ because $b_{ij}$ indices are $i,j \in V = \{1,2,3,...,n\}$? It's probably a typo in your source.

Comment: @plshelp. Thanks. This how incident matrix is designed. Rows for vertices and columns for edges, so we take edge by edge.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Comment: $b_{ik}$ is the entry of $B$ on row $i$ and column $k$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus. Thank you. Once we take the transpose of the incident matrix $B$, we would then have what please? As columns are edges and rows are vertices of incident matrix, but if we take transpose of incident matrix, then rows will be edges and columns vertices. So, if we multiplied $b_{ik}b_{jk}$ what we should get then?

Comment: $B_{jk}=B^T_{kj}$. So what is written is equivalent to $\sum_{k} B_{ik}B^T_{kj}$, which is exactly the definition of matrix multiplication between $B$ and $B^T$

Comment: @nirshahar. Thank you very much. So I am referring here to the meaning rather than notation please. I am just trying to ask if the rows of incident matrix $B$ are vertices and the columns are edges incident to those vertices, so if we take the transpose of incident matrix $B$, we will get $B^T$, which have the rows as edges and columns as vertices please?

Comment: Well yes, thats what transposing a matrix does

Comment: @nirshahar. Thank you. So, if we take the sum of the row of incident matrix, we will get degree of a vertex, what will be the interpretation of $b_{ik}b_{jk}$ please?

Comment: It represents the number of common vertices are adjacent to both $v_i$ and $v_j$

Comment: @nirshahar. Thank you and I appreciate your responses. Lastly please, so $B^T$ would be $ \mid E \mid \times \mid V \mid$ since $B$ is $ \mid V \mid \times \mid E \mid$ please?